# What might cause my film SLR to produce partially black/missing frames?

Tags: film, developing, error, mechanical-shutter

Been shooting on my Pentax ME and been having some problems.

Firstly, some pictures are missing off my rolls of films when I get them developed, like around 10 pictures. I guess this could have been at the fault of the lab, but it's happened a few times which leads me to believe it's some kind of fault with the camera. Any suggestions?

Also, I keep getting a black block on the bottom of some photographs (see below). I feel like this is a mechanical fault, and probably something to do with the shutter needing realigning, but was wondering if, again, anyone had any suggestions?[image: Black Block 1] [image: Black Block 2]

Comment: With respect to the missing pictures... What length roll of film are you putting in the camera? 24-exposure, 36-exposure? How many photos are you getting back? Are you getting the negatives back? Are you getting prints? Can you identify images in your negatives for which you are missing the print?

Comment: These are two separate issues and should be asked in separate questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Got back my film - Nikon FM2 missing shots, blue marks, what happened?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/93812/got-back-my-film-nikon-fm2-missing-shots-blue-marks-what-happened)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The dark lower third of your photos looks like a stuck shutter blade.

To confirm my hunch: open your camera back (with no film loaded, of course) and shoot at manual - B setting. Keep the shutter pressed. Watch whether shutter opens fully. Pay special attention to the upper blade (the image is reversed).

As for the missing pictures: shutter malfunction is a possible culprit, but it is one of many.

Comment: It could also be an electronic flash synchronization issue (using a shutter speed faster than the X-sync speed), although these don't look particularly like flash photos.

Comment: It does look like the shutter leaf is not opening completely or is not synchronized .

Answer (score -1):

Most likely a too fast shutter speed while using flash. Check the sync speed of your camera/flash.

Comment: Do these pictures look as shot with flash?